# How to get table and columns comment in JPA Buddy revers engendering

Tags: reverse-engineering, jpa-buddy

I just bougth JPA Buddy plugin for Intellij Idea. It doesn't copy table and column comments into generated Entity from DB. In my case I use Postgres. I know that such posibility exists in Jboss tools revers engendering. https://developer.jboss.org/message/819421#819421

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket in the JPA Buddy issue tracker: https://issues.jpa-buddy.com/issue/JPAB-1954/Support-orghibernateannotationsComment-annotation.

P.S. Would be nice if you could share the way you want comments to appear in the entity class as @Comment or as a JavaDoc.

Comment: The best is the possibility to choose @Comment or as a JavaDoc, BTW neither of them transferred to DTO as OpenApi 3.0 and Swagger 2.X Annotations than also would be great.

Comment: Noted! Follow the issue, we will raise its priority!

Comment: To watch the issue I have to log in youtrack. I haven't found possibility to do this.

Comment: Fair enough! Just edited the answer! Could you check it please